# Local stability of a min-max point

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

Suppose I have a smooth scalar function $f(x,y)$ where $x,y$ can be vectors. I am interested in finding a saddle-point:

$$\min_x \max_y f(x,y)\qquad(1)$$

I have the intuition that at such a point, the Hessian of $f$,

$$\partial^2 f = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial
  y}\\
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial
  y^2}
\end{array}\right)$$

satisfies that: 1) the upper-left block $\partial^2f/\partial x^2$ is positive definite, and 2) the lower-right block $\partial^2f/\partial y^2$ is negative definite.

My question is whether these conditions are enough to guarantee that the point is indeed a saddle-point that solves (1), at least if the domain is restricted to a local neighborhood.

Comment: there a difference between 'a' saddle point and the solution of (1); a point that satisfies your conditions on the Hessian does not necessarily solve (1)

Comment: @LinAlg Note my last sentence in the question. Assume the domain of $f$ is restricted to a local neighborhood of the saddle-point. Also assume $f$ is smooth (I edited to the question to add this assumption explicitly).

Comment: @Tobias Actually I think it's not enough. Because you can move in a direction that mixes $x$ and $y$ components together, and it's not guaranteed what will happen to the function values in those directions. So I am still not sure what the correct condition is on the Hessian

Comment: @Tobias Remember $x$ and $y$ denote high-dimensional vectors in my question. I think your argument only applies to scalars $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @becko thanks! I did not read that properly. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Define the function $\psi(x)$ by the condition:

$$\max_y f (x, y) = f (x, \psi (x))$$

That is, $y=\psi(x)$ is the value of $y$ that maximizes $f(x,y)$ for a fixed $x$. It follows that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x, \psi (x)) = 0, \qquad \frac{\partial^2
f}{\partial y^2} (x, \psi (x)) < 0$$

where the second inequality is to be interpreted as that the Hessian matrix with respect to the $y$ variables is negative definite at this point.

This definition also determines the derivative of $\psi(x)$ with respect to $x$, because:

$$\frac{d}{d x} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x, \psi (x))
\right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y} (x, \psi (x)) +
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} (x, \psi (x)) \frac{\partial \psi
(x)}{\partial x} = 0$$

which implies:

$$\frac{\partial \psi (x)}{\partial x} = - \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial
y^2} (x, \psi (x)) \right)^{- 1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y} (x,
\psi (x))$$

Note that here, $\psi(x)$ is a vector valued function. Therefore the derivative is actually a Jacobian matrix, and the right-hand side of this equation is a matrix product between the inverse Hessian of $f$ with respect to $y$, and the mixed second derivatives with respect to $x,y$.

Now we return to the original optimization problem:

$$\min_x \max_y f (x, y) = \min_x f(x,\psi(x))$$

The minimization of $f(x,\psi(x))$ with respect to $x$ is guaranteed by the two usual conditions:

$$\frac{\partial f (x, \psi (x))}{\partial x} = 0, \qquad \frac{\partial^2 f
(x, \psi (x))}{\partial x^2} > 0$$

where the derivatives are "total" in the sense that $\psi(x)$ must also be differentiated. We have

$$\frac{\partial f (x, \psi (x))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
(x, \psi (x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x, \psi (x)) \frac{\partial
\psi (x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, \psi (x))$$

because $f(x,y)$ is stationary in $y$ at $y=\psi(x)$. Next,

$$\frac{\partial^2 f (x, \psi (x))}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2
f}{\partial x^2} (x, \psi (x)) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}
(x, \psi (x)) \frac{\partial \psi (x)}{\partial x}$$

Substituting the derivative of $\psi(x)$:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f (x, \psi (x))}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2
f}{\partial x^2} (x, \psi (x)) - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}
(x, \psi (x)) \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} (x, \psi (x))
\right)^{- 1} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} (x, \psi (x))$$

In summary, we find the following conditions for the original optimization problem:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0,
\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0,
\quad
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} < 0,
\quad 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x
\partial y} \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \right)^{- 1}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} > 0$$

The first two conditions are the normal gradient stationary condition. The third condition comes from the inner maximization on $y$. The last condition is the tricky one, demanding the positive definiteness of a certain combination of the blocks of the Hessian of $f$, which is different from the original conditions of the OP.

In fact, this is just the Shur's complement of the $y$-block of the Hessian. I'm not sure if its eigenvalues can be related in some way to the eigenvalues of the full Hessian.

Comment: you haven't touched the issue of multiple local optima

Comment: @LinAlg No I haven't. But also my question was not intended to touch this issue. Which is why in the end of the question I restrict the domain of $f$ to a local neighborhood of the saddle-point.

Comment: After writing this answer I found this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00618, which gives the same condition.